# Goats with venomous horns?

Tags: biology, creature-design

I need a species of goat with horns that inject venom into you. How can I pull this off realistically? You see, I hate unrealistic things, so to have my venomous goats from hell be unreasonable would kill me!

They need to attack people because they have claimed human’s territory and attack and hump children. I want this to be child friendly. How can I make their horns venomous yet child friendly?

Comment: Note that goats use their horns to butt. It is rare for them to use the points of their horns and if they do when fighting, they can get locked together. Can you draw a diagram (or show photos/videos) showing how the horns are used?

Comment: Their horns have many spikes on them. Covering them. All over the place! That shoot out when they’re angry. So, the tiny spikes have poison.

Comment: That could be tricky to explain. Goat horns are made of keratin - the same as human fingernails. In effect keratin is dead as soon as it is formed. I think we need at least a diagram showing how these horns look and work. It doesn't have to be a professional picture, just a rough sketch.

Comment: The horns are made out of skin

Comment: I don't mean to be grammar Nazi, but I think the term here is "venomous." "*Poison is ingested, venom is injected.*" https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KnJ4_xRfxpA&list=LLktmHCmy2z-mn1p_uyzvyWA&index=3906

Comment: What is with all the questions recently about venomous animals in heat attacking people?

Comment: What’s the other question about venomous animals in heat?

Comment: @Palbitt - Lol, strictly you are being a *semantics* Nazi if anything! Grammar relates to structure, semantics relates to meaning.

Comment: Yeah! Chasly’s wright

Comment: @Johndoe https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/184542/is-a-venomous-bird-possible

Comment: Wow! Birds sure are cool!

Comment: You know, if you combine the concept of poisonous frogs, deer horn velvet, and your average, cunning, ornery goat... you might get something along the lines of what you're looking for. (I'd make this a formal answer, but I don't have the time. If someone wants to chase down the details and turn it into an answer, they have my blessing.) The fact that the velvet would tear during combat adds an interesting limitation that could be cool for your story, too.

Comment: Also... ***they do what to children?*** Considering the [beat down we're taking over execution questions and SE's proposed solution](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7973/40609) you might do us a favor and keep your post child-friendly. We get what you're trying to achieve, you just need to remember folks of all ages come to this site.

Comment: 94 years olds don’t need no home trainins from the likes of you

Answer (score 4):

**Like stinging nettle**

There are many plants that use tiny hollow needles with poison. Check the Gimpy Gimpy for some horror stories. Having the goat as a species immune to it's own poison and injecting venom in anyone who touches the horns due to the tiny needles is a plausible method. With head butting people you can also be reasonably certain the tiny needles can enter through clothes and fur.

Don't want plants but a more animalistic base? There are a lot of caterpillar species with venomous hairs that can trigger all kinds of nasty when coming just in contact with skin. Same applies here. Just have something nasty grow on the horns. Small amounts of incredibly lethal venom is all around nature, although mostly not intended for humans luckily. The only caveat is that I don’t know if a specific diet is needed to create the venom.

Comment: Could I have the goats eat poisonous frogs to generate venom?

Comment: @Johndoe possibly their current food is enough. Caterpillars eat leaves and a few thing besides and can synthesize venom. Frogs can do it from bugs. A goat has the reputation to eat *everything*. Again, I'm no expert, but their current diet might be enough.

Answer (score 4):

***A Different Definition of Toxic Horns:***

If you want REALLY plausible goats that have lethal side-effects of head-butting, I would go in a different route. First, forward-facing horns are going to give piercing wounds more effectively, and are the opposite function for goats, but a trivial evolution.

1. Your goats have diseased horns like the Komodo Dragon's bite. They regularly stab their horns into the fecal material of their own or other species. Folds and pockets in the horns provide a friendly environment for bacterial growth. A few (like Clostridium perfringens) are especially deadly and lead almost anyone injured by these beasts to die a slow, horrible, toxin-driven death (although the toxins are bacterial). Or perhaps you like ergot, and want the victims to behave in erratic, bizarre ways. How family friendly did you want this?
2. Your goats have developed a tolerance for especially lethal plants like belladonna, and regularly rub their horns in the bushes of such plants. Their horns are now coated with lethal toxins that can have whatever fun effects you care to name. This can be anything from neurotoxins to opiates to nicotine. What weird or horrible effects would you like? If you want something that won't kill children, then hallucinogenic compounds will cause bizarre behavior and render enemies helpless, but not be (directly) lethal.

Answer (score 0):

If your goats are fictitious you can break a lot of normal goat rules without delving into unreasonable territory. It's the delivery of the venom that's important, not the biological method - do they butt their target? If so give them the horn equivalent of dewclaws, just smaller horns that branch out at the base of the larger horns so when their skulls come into contact with their target they penetrate the skin and inject a toxin. Do these goats actually gore their targets? If so, the horns would need to be configured like a bull's, and the impaling would do a freak of a ton more damage than poison.

You could also make the horns sort of serated, they don't impale, but can scrape or break the skin, like being whacked with a cheese grater. The material of the horn could be constantly growing and shedding, and perhaps its the flakes from the outer layer that are toxic.

Comment: That wouldn’t work! My goats are the size of a chihuahua!

Comment: Then clearly you're reduced to pharmacology delivered at range from gas-powered tranquilizer guns that grow naturally in the gumdrop forest.

Comment: Thank you SO much! The forest shall now have gumdrops growing on the tree and the goats living in it will squirt their ejaculate at the children! :)

Answer (score 0):

This made me think of the venom that comes from the fangs of snakes. To deliver venom, snakes have hollow fangs that act like hypodermic needles. When a snake bites, muscles in its head squeeze the venom glands. This pushes the liquid through its fangs muscles in its head squeeze the venom glands. This pushes the liquid through its fangs and into the flesh of its prey. [Link to More Snake Venom Info](https://letstalkscience.ca/educational-resources/stem-in-context/how-snake-venom-kills-and-saves-lives) Therefore, if the horns of the goat were sharp and hollow, upon contact to the victim the venom can exit through the tip of the horn using a similar science to the fangs of venomous snakes.

Comment: some venomous animals just have grooved teeth. presumably that is how hollow teeth evolve.